# Возможно ли в unity input manager установить несколько кнопок как Positive Button в одном axis?

Tags: unity3d, input

В Unity есть такая штука, как Input Manager, где я могу поставить определенную клавишу отвечать за определенную axis, после чего получать ее из скрипта. Однако могу ли я поставить несколько клавиш сразу?

Например, чтобы ось Jump получала позитивное значение при нажатии пробела ИЛИ стрелки вверх, а негативное - при нажатии шифта ИЛИ стрелки вниз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, достаточно добавить 2 значении в Size, один положительный Test1 а другой отрицательный Test2
https://yadi.sk/d/8yV8FWw9nEBo4w?w=1

Comment: Да, но обычно я бы получал нажатие кнопки с помощью условия с Input.GetAxis("Name"), а тут как если из сразу две с разными названиями?

Comment: Честно говоря с Input Manager мало кто используют ну кроме Mouse X и Mouse Y, начните делать свою систему назначение кнопок в игре типо, Настройки > Настройки управления.

Comment: Да? Я читал, что наоборот неправильно использовать простое принятие кнопок и делать через Input manager. No есть вы предлагаете делать `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Up) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))`

Comment: Ну лично да,  я не использую Input Manager кроме Mouse X и Y потому что я не хочу использовать диалоговое окно при старте игры, поэтому вы можете как и прежде использовать Input Manager

Comment: О каком окне вы говорите? Я предполагаю, что управление в игре осуществляется стандартными Вверх-влево-вниз-вправо или WASD. Диалоговое окно при старте игры - это что? Пользовательский выбор, какие кнопки он хочет использовать для передвижения (например)

Comment: Это окно, https://images.app.goo.gl/cx36DiAHJRnUZcFM9

Comment: Что это вообще? Оно у меня никогда не показывалось